# Why is my code on pastebin even though I didn't put it there?

Tags: discussion, third-party

I recently asked a question which I later deleted due to the simplicity and shortness of my code, but then I found it on Pastebin. What the heck!?

Link to deleted question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61974/basic-generator-expression-function). *(2kers can click here.)*

## Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How do you "stumble" upon a pastebin snippet? When I look at pastebin I see 8 pastes going back a full *26 seconds* in time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uhm, no idea how it got there....

**EDIT** The pastebin was created at Sept 4, 03:55:07 PM CDT, the Code Review post was created at Sept 4, 20:52:59Z

By my calculation (with the PM-to-24h, and CDT-to-Zulu time: -5hr), the PasteBin was created at

```
Sept 4, 03:55:07 PM CDT
Sept 4, 15:55:07    CDT
Sept 4, 20:55:07    Z
```

The Pastebin was created.... 2 minutes and 19 seconds after you posted the question, and before you deleted the question at 20:57:30Z

But... does it matter?

Your question was available for people to see for ... 5 minutes? It's more than enough for someone to paste the code there. Google is also that fast at indexing things (stack exchange helps them), that it takes no time for these things to happen.

If you are concerned, you can do two things:

1. ask Pastebin to remove the content (DMCA request?)
2. not put content on CodeReview which you do not want copied to other places.